# If cell value is in list then replace with third value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to replace any values in the list with the replace value.

[image: EG]

I can't seem to figure out what functions to use

```
Sub findandreplace()
Dim WIP As Range
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
Set SrchRng = Selection
Set WIP = Workbooks("Long life check").Sheets("WIP").Columns("C:D")

For Each cel In SrchRng
    'if cel.value is contained within WIP then replace with value from column D
Next cel
End Sub
```

Once ran A11 would be I001080.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like the following

```
Sub findandreplace()
    Dim WIP As Range
    Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
    Set SrchRng = Selection
    Set WIP = Workbooks("Long life check").Sheets("WIP").Columns("C:D")

    With ActiveSheet.Columns("A")
        For Each cel In SrchRng
            .Cells.Replace cel, cel.Offset(0, 1)
        Next cel
    End With
End Sub
```

Select your 'Find' range and run